# How do I insert a newline in Node.js when using Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to create a Node.js application on Heroku that will output 10 different ASCII faces (I already have the module needed for that). Using the Node tutorial on Heroku, I've set it up to output 10 faces. However, when I try to actually run the code, it puts all of the faces *inline* with each other. How should I try to make it so that the faces are outputted (if that's even a word) on their own lines?

My current `index.js` is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var result = ''
    var times = process.env.TIMES || 5
    for (i=0; i < times; i++)
        result += cool();
    response.send(result);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node app is running on port: " + app.get('port'))
})
```

I have a `.env` file already set up for Foreman to use (when testing locally) that contains the following:
    `TIMES=9`

If you want to have a look at the output, head on over [here](https://ascii-face-generator.herokuapp.com/).

TL;DR: How do I use newlines in Node?

Comment: You need to either send HTML or tell the browser that you're sending `text/plain`.

Comment: Alrighty then @SLaks. How would I do that? (Sorry, I'm _really_ new to Node.)

Comment: How do you do which?

Comment: Tell the browser that I'm sending `text/plain` should be fine. Also, how would I integrate the newline character (`\n`) into my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visited the site in question and did a View -> Source.  There's no markup of any kind like HTML, BODY, etc.  I assume that the browser then would interpret the output as HTML.  This ought to work since we're using an HTML tag and a pair of PRE tags to indicate that if we see a hard return ('\n') then the browser should display it.

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  var result = '<html><pre>';
  var times = process.env.TIMES || 5
  for (i=0; i < times; i++)
    result += cool() + '\n';
  result += '</pre></html>';
  response.send(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This one seemed to work exactly as I hoped!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the browser assumes that web servers send HTML.
HTML ignores newlines.

If you aren't sending HTML, you need to specify that by setting a different type:

```
response.header("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

To actually send a newline, just concatenate `'\n'` to your string.